# BaseAdapter in Custom ListView, How i can make it more robust in null views

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, baseadapter

I have this code that usually works fine but in some devices with Android 9 only im getting this exception:

```
HistoryListViewAdapter+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetView>b__0 ()
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args)
JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters)
HtmlCompat.FromHtml (System.String source, System.Int32 flags)
HistoryListViewAdapter+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetView>b__0 ()
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (System.Action action)
HistoryListViewAdapter.GetView (System.Int32 position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
BaseAdapter.n_GetView_ILandroid_view_View_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Int32 position, System.IntPtr native_convertView, System.IntPtr native_parent)
androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat.fromHtml HtmlCompat.java:148
crc64441aa66e1467637c.HistoryListViewAdapter.n_getView(Native Method)
crc64441aa66e1467637c.HistoryListViewAdapter.getView HistoryListViewAdapter.java:56
android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView AbsListView.java:2375
androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onLayout ViewPager.java:1775
android.view.View.layout View.java:20871
androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout CoordinatorLayout.java:918
android.view.View.layout View.java:20871
androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout DrawerLayout.java:1263
android.view.View.layout View.java:20871
```

Im guessing the problem lies in my adapter, it needs improvement to handle all situations more effectively, but im not sure how i can improve my code, here is my adapter code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidX.Core.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace KinoStats
{
    public class HistoryListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
    {
        private readonly Activity Activity;
        private readonly List<string> Data;

        public HistoryListViewAdapter(Activity Activity, List<string> Data) : base()
        {
            this.Activity = Activity;
            this.Data = Data;
        }

        public override string this[int position] => Data[position];

        public override int Count => Data.Count;

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SingleHistoryListViewItem, null);

            var historyItemTextView = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.HistoryItemTextView);

            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                historyItemTextView.SetText(
                HtmlCompat.FromHtml(Data[position],
                    HtmlCompat.FromHtmlModeLegacy),
                TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `in some devices with Android 9 only im getting this exception` mean? Do you get this adapter work on other device?

Comment: Yes its working on hundreds other devices with any android OS